# Having if-else condition inside promises chains

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have a promises chain and inside some points I have `if-else` condition like the following:

```
.then(function() {

   if(isTrue) {
     // do something returning a promise
   } else {
     // do nothing - just return
     return;
   }
})
.then(function() {
   ...
})
```

Honestly I don't like this pattern. I feel it wrong. I mean using just a plain return without anything. Do you have some idea to make look different this code?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks and where should be the change in the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `else { return; }` part can simply be completely omitted without changing the code's meaning:

```
.then(function() {
    if (isTrue) {
        // do something returning a promise
    }
})
```

Functions do return `undefined` anyway by default.

Comment: and automatically will continue to the next then?

Comment: As I said, it's equivalent to what you currently have. Yes, it will resolve with the value `undefined` and call the next `.then()`s callback with that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have tested the code. And recognized that this is not working like you expected. Let me explain you:

```
function getPromise() {
  callSomeFunctionWhichReturnsPromise().then(function(result) {
    return result; // You hope, that this will be logged on the console? nope, you have to do it here instead.
    console.log('logged in the promise', result); // This will work
  });
}

var result = getPromise();
console.log(result); // undefined!!!
```

you could instead do this:

```
function getPromise() {
  return callSomeFunctionWhichReturnsPromise();
}

var result = getPromise();
result.then(console.log); // will call console.log(arguments)
```